# ASP.NET MVC And Ajax Send Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I trying send data to my controller. Controller sends all data to client correcly but from client to controller not..

My front code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#MessageSend").click(function () {

        var serviceURL = '/User/Chat';

        var model = {
            Message: $("#Message").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: model,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            alert(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

And my controller, I have two versions - non of those versions works.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Chat(ChatMessage model)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model.Message);
    return Json("chamara");
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Chat(string Message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Message);
    return Json("chamara");
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(model)`

Comment: There is ambiguous between actions: same name and verb - leave first one.

Comment: thanks, now all works

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, hence
You need to change the data in a way that the Json can "understand" it
for that change to

`data: JSON.stringify(model)`

for more information about it look [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, seems you are trying to send a JSON to User controller but your controller is expecting a string (controller example 2).

Also, it is a good practice to create specific classes for binding events via jquery such as "js-messageSend". It will minimize the chance of your script breaking if you need to change the Message class for any reason in the future, but forget that you have an event on it.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MessageSend").click(function () {

        var messageText = $("#Message").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/User/Chat',
            data: { Message: messageText },
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            alert(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome!